# Adding Items to an array in a round robin fashion in powershell?

Tags: arrays, list, powershell, csv

I am starting a project where a .csv file with basic names will be the input.
I need to step through all of the names in this .csv and add them to lists/arrays that have a max limit of 20. Also if the name is already in the list, then it needs to move onto the next list. But the number of lists/arrays that need to be made is based on the total count of the csv. There is no limit to the amount of times a name can be entered but I need to go round robin in all the arrays so the names are spaced out evenly.

So I need something like if ($CSVfilenames.count =< 80) 4 arrays would be made and the names would be added in a round robin fashion.

Would it be best to use a multidimensional array for this or would anyone have a better option on how to get started. I am really stumped on how to begin and the first few things I tried yielded disaster.

Still pretty new at power shell.

Comment: Is it possible to have more duplicates than lists? Say, 80 rows -> 4 arrays, but five rows containing name "Bob"?

Comment: Show us some of the disasters. Maybe they just need a little polish...

Comment: @vonPryz yes that is perfectly fine and expected action. There is a possibility that there could be a large number of the same name so it would just need to keep adding the names but If its adding multiple entries then it would need to be even so having one with 2 and the other 3 with 1 is ok but having one with 4 and the others with just 1 is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick draft based on hash tables. First, count how many groups are needed. Divide input's size by group size and round up. Then create collections for storing the elements. Loop through the input and store each element into a collection.

What's missing is how to handle duplicates. It's easy to look up if one exists, as hashtables have `.ContainsKey()` method just for that. The logic how to pick up anohter a hash table is left as an exercise to the reader.

This solution does not preserve original order, as hash tables are by definition unordered sets. There's [ordered dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.contains?view=netcore-3.1) too, which can be accessed via type accelerator `[ordered]`.

```
# Some test cases
$data = @('basil', 'marjoram', 'aniseed', 'parsely', 'chives', 'sage', 'fennel', 'oregano', 'thyme', 'tarragon', 'rosemary') # 11 unique elements
$data = @('basil', 'marjoram', 'aniseed', 'parsely', 'chives', 'sage', 'fennel', 'oregano', 'thyme', 'tarragon', 'rosemary', 'laurel') # 12 unique elements
$data = @('basil', 'marjoram', 'aniseed', 'parsely', 'parsely', 'chives', 'sage', 'fennel', 'oregano', 'thyme', 'tarragon', 'rosemary') # 12 elements, one duplicate, good index
$data = @('basil', 'marjoram', 'aniseed', 'parsely', 'chives', 'sage', 'fennel', 'parsely', 'oregano', 'thyme', 'tarragon', 'rosemary') # 12 elements, one duplicate, bad index

# How big a group will be
$groupMaxSize = 4
# Divide list size with group size and round up
# This many groups are needed
$numGroups = [math]::ceiling($data.Count / $groupMaxSize)

# Create hash table for each group. Store in an array
$hh = @()
for($i=0;$i -le $numGroups; ++$i) {
    $hh += @{}
}

# Iterate through the data. Each element index mod numGroups will tell
# into which group it will belong.
for($i=0;$i -lt $data.Count; ++$i) {
    # Which group will the element go into?
    $idx = $i % $numGroups
    # Hashtable requires unique keys, so only add elements that don't exist.
    # Key is the data, value is group index.
    if(-not $hh[$idx].ContainsKey($data[$i])) {
        $hh[$idx].Add($data[$i], $idx)
    } else {
        # Element alreayd existed, add logic to look up next free hashtable
        write-host "collision!" $data[$i]
    } 
}

# print results
$hh
collision!  parsely

Name                           Value
----                           -----
basil                          0
chives                         0
oregano                        0
thyme                          1
marjoram                       1
sage                           1
aniseed                        2
fennel                         2
tarragon                       2
rosemary                       3
parsely                        3
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you